# Encoded image gives different code when it was send wtih smtplib

Tags: python-3.x, base64, smtplib

I've tried to encode an image with this method :

```
def resim_ac(self):
    dosya_ismi = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Resim Aç", os.getenv("HOME"))

    with open(dosya_ismi[0], "rb") as file:

        image = file.read()

        encode_image = base64.encodestring(image)
    if  str(encode_image) != "":
        return str(encode_image)
    else:
        return ""
```

encoded_image equals to image: `b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAI...BlLm9yZ5vuPBoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=\n'`(It is encoded image)

Whenever I try to send this code with email with this method:

```
    mesaj = MIMEMultipart()

    mesaj_govdesi2 = MIMEText(str(self.resim_ac), "plain")


    mesaj.attach(mesaj_govdesi2)


    mesaj["Subject"] = self.subject_text.text()  #LineEdit



    mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()

    mail.login(self.email, self.passw)  # e-mail adress and it's password
    mail.sendmail(self.email,self.email_to, mesaj.as_string())
    print("Mail Sended....")



    mail.close()
```

It gives me this[image]
rather than  `b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAI...BlLm9yZ5vuPBoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=\n'`

My question is why these two are different? And how can I make them same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I solved it. The problem is that I should define encode_image with self. So it is easily called in another function in the class.

```
content = str(self.encryption())
        mesaj = MIMEMultipart()

        mesaj_govdesi = MIMEText(str(content), "plain")
        mesaj_govdesi2 = MIMEText(str(self.encode_image), "plain")

        mesaj.attach(mesaj_govdesi)
        mesaj.attach(mesaj_govdesi2)


        mesaj["Subject"] = self.subject_text.text()  #LineEdit


        try:
            mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

            mail.ehlo()
            mail.starttls()

            mail.login(self.email, self.passw)  # e-mail adress and it's password
            mail.sendmail(self.email,self.email_to, mesaj.as_string())
```